# Gradient Descent in MLPs using Computational Graphs

Tags: neural-networks, research, gradient-descent

I'm working through *Deep Learning* by Goodfellow et al. The textbook introduces backpropagation for MLPs in page 203 (http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/mlp.html). However, it does not expand further and illustrate the (full or stochastic) gradient descent update.

I'd like to confirm the full gradient descent update is as below. Is this correct?

**Gradient descent derivation**
[image: Gradient descent]

**From *Deep Learning***
[image: Deep Learning Backprop]

Comment: What exactly is the part you don't understand and want to have elaborated? What exactly do you want to know about it?

Comment: Your question already includes a complete answer to the original problem but no question *about* this answer. Thus, only "yes/no" answers may remain, helping neither you nor future visitors. Please read related meta discussions [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/) and adjust your question accordingly, e.g. by formulating a specific question about a single element of your answer you are uncertain about. If you just want general feedback, you are welcome to visit us in [chat].

Comment: @Discretelizard I'd like to know whether the full gradient descent algorithm I've derived is correct or not

Comment: Note that you can use LaTeX (directly, instead of in an image) here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.